# theoretical analysis of multiplications in function

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

Do
a
theoretical
analysis
for
the
running
time
of
the
following
C++
function
MMultiply.
Count
the
number
of
multiplications
MMultiply
does
as
a
function
of
n
because
in
this
case,
n
is
the
size
of
the
input/size
of
the
problem.
Show
your
workings.
Express
the
answer
in
big
O
notation.

```
int I(int i, int j, int n)
{
    return n * i + j;
}

int sProduct(const int A[],const int B[],int i, int j, int n)
{
    int t = 0;
    for( int k=0; k<n; k++ )
    {
        int d = A[ I(i,k,n) ] * B[ I(k,j,n) ];
        t += d * d;
    }
    return t;
}

void MMultiply(const int A[], const int B[], int C[], int n)
{
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
        for( int j=0; j<n; j++ )
            C[ I(i,j,n) ] = sProduct(A, B, i, j, n );
}
```

Answer was found to be O(n^3), but I dont understand how this was computed.

The outer loop in MMultiply gives n, the inner loop is n, so then looking at the functions with multiplication there are 3......M(n)=n*n(....) then I'm lost on how to look at the other functions.The T(n) and C(n) notations are also throwing me off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `i` goes from 0 to n, so `n` times in total.
- for each `i`, `j` goes from 0 to n, so `n` times for each `i`, `n*n` times in total.
- for each `j`, `k` goes from 0 to n, so `n` times for each `j`, `n*n*n` times in total.

The lines that do work, i.e.:

```
int d = A[ I(i,k,n) ] * B[ I(k,j,n) ];
t += d * d;
```

get executed `n*n*n` = O(n<sup>3</sup>) times.

There is another line that does work. The assignment here:

```
C[ I(i,j,n) ] = sProduct(A, B, i, j, n );
```

gets executed `n*n` = O(n<sup>2</sup>) times. So the entire algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>). As `n` grows the n<sup>2</sup> term is insignificant, so the entire algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>).

That gives us the upper bound, i.e. what happens in the worst case. Note that even in the best case those lines still get executed n<sup>3</sup> times, so you can say that the lower bound is Ω(n<sup>3</sup>) as well. That means that the algorithm is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) (i.e. lower and upper bounds are the same).